# Are Interlocked* functions useful on shared memory?

Tags: winapi, ipc, shared-memory, interlocked

Two Windows processes have memory mapped the same shared file.  If the file consists of counters, is it appropriate to use the `Interlocked*` functions (like `InterlockedIncrement`) to update those counters?  Will those synchronize access across processes?  Or do I need to use something heavier, like a mutex?  Or perhaps the shared-memory mechanism itself ensures consistent views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684122%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> ...
>
> ### The Interlocked API
>
> The interlocked functions provide a
>   simple mechanism for synchronizing
>   access to a variable that is shared by
>   multiple threads. They also perform
>   operations on variables in an atomic
>   manner. The threads of different
>   processes can use these functions if
>   the variable is in shared memory.

So, yes, it is safe with your shared memory approach.

Answer (score 7):

The interlocked functions are intended for exactly that type of use.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684122.aspx:

> The threads of different processes can use these functions if the variable is in shared memory.

Of course, if you need to have more than one item updated atomically, you'll need to go with a mutex or some other synchronization object that works across processes. There's nothing built-in to the shared memory mechanism to provide synchronization to access to the shared memory - you'll need to use the interlocked functions or a synchronization object.

Comment: But does InterlockedIncrement work *cross-process*? I think that's the relevant question--and to the best of my knowledge, it does not.

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683614.aspx: "This function generates a full memory barrier (or fence) to ensure that memory operations are completed in order."

Comment: As long as the memory is mapped to the same physical address, Interlocked is fine. It results in making sure the memory bus is locked for all processors and their caches coherent for the given address, nothing having to do with processes.

Comment: I guess what wasn't clear to me is whether the file mappings always result in the memory being mapped to the same physical address or if the OS copies data around to make it look that way.  With all the layers (virtual address, view, mapping, physical address, and file), it's never been clear to me where the merge point was.  The shared memory sections in MSDN make some comments about coherence guarantees only if you use the same (or duplicated) mapping handle.

Comment: Under the hood any mutexes stored in shared memory that you would use are making use of the same memory fences and lock instructions that Interlocked* uses.

Comment: @Freed: Not on any modern CPU. I believe it was last true on the Pentium, but false on the Pentium Pro and all later CPUs. Nevertheless, the behavior is the same, but only the cache line is locked. No buses are locked. (Nor need they be.)